# alarm or pop up Message application

Tags: c#, sql, windows, forms, alarm

My code for saving the details in the database is

```
    private void BtnSaveEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validation())
        {
            string cs = "Data Source=Ansar-Laptop;Initial Catalog=EventMngmnt;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into NewEvent_Table (eventName,eventDate,time,AmPm,eventLocation,description) " +
                    " values ('" + txtEventName.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "','" + txtTime.Text + "','" + comboBxAmPm.Text + "','" + comboBxLocation.Text + "','" + TxtDescription.Text + "')", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I want an alarm or a pop up Message to be shown when the day and time of the event comes, it should read the day and time from the database and check the current time and day and remind me.
one more thing, my application should get open as i turn on my pc

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Put using whenever you're working with IDisposable: using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...)) { ...

Comment: but how to read the day and time from the database and check the current time and day and remind me.

Answer (score 0):

You required following tools to create mention application:

[`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[`System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now set `Interval` less than 1 min so that in every 1 min you can check for database record for alarm. You can register `Timer_Tick` event of `Timer` to do so.

Show `BallonTip` of `NotifyIcon` if time get match for systemTime. You can even show small form to notify user.

To add starup path of application you can use following code to do so:

```
public static void CreateStartupShortcut(string applicationName)
{
    string _startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
    WshShell _shell = new WshShell();
    //
    string _shortcutAddress = _startupFolder + @"\" + applicationName + ".lnk";
    IWshShortcut _shortcut = (IWshShortcut)_shell.CreateShortcut(_shortcutAddress);
    //
    _shortcut.Description = "Start up shortcut link for application " + applicationName + ". Delete shortcut to if you dont want to run application on stat up";
    _shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
    _shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
    _shortcut.Save();
}
```

Comment: How to check for date&time in the database, and then the alarm must beep